# How to enforce braces in vscode settings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to move my code style setting from webstorm over to vscode and I am unable to find the equivalent setting that matches IF_BRACE_FORCE code style setting for webstorm.

What I am trying to accomplish is making

```
if (x>5) return true;
```

to format on save to

```
if (x>5) {
  return true;
}
```

I am unable to find a setting on vscode to accomplish this.

These are the settings I am trying to transfer over to vscode from webstorm

```
<code_scheme name="Fyre-core">
    <option name="RIGHT_MARGIN" value="160" />
    <JSCodeStyleSettings>
        <option name="FORCE_SEMICOLON_STYLE" value="true" />
        <option name="USE_DOUBLE_QUOTES" value="false" />
        <option name="INDENT_CHAINED_CALLS" value="false" />
    </JSCodeStyleSettings>
    <XML>
        <option name="XML_LEGACY_SETTINGS_IMPORTED" value="true" />
    </XML>
    <codeStyleSettings language="JavaScript">
        <option name="KEEP_BLANK_LINES_IN_CODE" value="1" />
        <option name="IF_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
        <option name="DOWHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
        <option name="WHILE_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
        <option name="FOR_BRACE_FORCE" value="3" />
    </codeStyleSettings>
</code_scheme>
```

Comment: I realized I misunderstood your question. You wanted if statement to automatically add braces on format on save. I'm very sorry for giving you false hope. I deleted my answer out of shame. (Still, "prettier" is a must extension in vscode as a code formatter)